# call function in function until condition is met

Tags: php

I am querying salesforce and each call returns:
2000 records
a boolean labeled "done"
the next url to query for next 2000 records.

if done is false, I need to make the next call to the next url and get next 2000 records, check for done, and repeat as necessary.

```
$accounts = array();

function listAccounts($data,$accounts){

    $ch = curl_init();
    //curl options
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $res = json_decode($result);
    foreach ($res->records as $k => $v){
            $accounts[] = $v->Name;
    }
    if ($res->done !== true){
            $data['listAccounts'] = $res->nextRecordsUrl;
            listAccounts($data,$accounts);
    }

    return $accounts;
}
print_r(listAccounts($data,$accounts));
```

The above, only returns the first 2000.  I would expect it to repeat the listAccounts function until $res->done !== true.  If I echo $v->name in the function, it prints all 5,000+ records I expect.  I know I need to pass the $accounts var to the next function call, but this doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pass by reference`

```
 function listAccounts($data,&$accounts);
```

Your Code

```
$accounts = array();
function listAccounts($data,&$accounts){
  $ch = curl_init();
  //curl options
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $res = json_decode($result);
  foreach ($res->records as $k => $v){
          $accounts[] = $v->Name;
  }
  if ($res->done !== true){
    $data['listAccounts'] = $res->nextRecordsUrl;
    listAccounts($data,$accounts);
  }

return $accounts;
}
print_r(listAccounts($data,$accounts));
```